# Most 5s in a 5x5 Super Minesweeper grid

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, minesweeper

In a Super™ Minesweeper grid each cell is either a mine or a value. A value in row $$ and column $$ represents the total number of mines located in row $$ or column $$.

What is the most number of 5s that can occur in a 5x5 Super™ Minesweeper grid? Good luck!

Comment: Would [optimization] be an appropriate tag?

Comment: Yes I suppose it is an optimization.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "the total number of mines located in row r AND column c."?

Comment: it depends how you interpret it. We are counting mines that are either in the same row or same column, they can't be in both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Number of fives:

> Twelve

One such grid:

> ```
>  X 5 X 5 X
>  5 X 5 X 5
>  X 5 X 5 X
>  5 X 5 X 5
>  X 5 X 5 X
> ```

Comment: Via integer linear programming, this value is optimal.

Comment: @RobPratt I expected it would be. Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: Well done! Pretty solution.